# Accessing second level scope from third level scope angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

[image]

As illustrated above I'm trying to access the second level 2 scope from level 3 scope from angular controller
but, parent comes as null and it is able to access Level1 scope though which i dont want

Need too access level2 scope from level3

> as you can see in below pic the level 2 scope from parent comes as
>   null

[image]

Comment: Please, share with us your code through https://jsfiddle.net/.

Comment: May be this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21404187/angular-scope-parent-is-null-a-bug-or-a-feature

Answer (score 0):

`angular.element(...).scope()` will get the scope(**not current scope**) which your target element belongs to.

In the below example, I have added four input(outside controllers, levelOne, levelTwo, levelThree) to make it clear(open console to confirm it).

```js
angular.module("app", [])
  .controller("levelOne", function($scope) {
    $scope.data = 'levelOne';
  })
  .controller("levelTwo", function($scope) {
    $scope.childData = 'levelTwo';
  })
  .controller("levelThree", function($scope) {
    $scope.grandChildData = 'levelThree';
    console.log($scope.$parent);
    var scope = angular.element(document.getElementById("input")).scope();
    var parentScope = angular.element(document.getElementById("levelOne")).scope();
    var childScope = angular.element(document.getElementById("levelTwo")).scope();
    var grandChildScope = angular.element(document.getElementById("levelThree")).scope();
    console.log('scope', scope);
    console.log('parentScope', parentScope);
    console.log('childScope', childScope);
    console.log('grandChildScope', grandChildScope);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <input id="input" type="text" value="not in controller">
  <hr>
  <div ng-controller="levelOne">
    <input id="levelOne" type="text" ng-model="data">
    <hr>
    <div ng-controller="levelTwo">
      <input id="levelTwo" type="text" ng-model="childData">
      <hr>
      <div ng-controller="levelThree">
        <input id="levelThree" type="text" ng-model="grandChildData">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and based on your provided screenshot, maybe you are fitted to the second situation(element belongs to **level1**'s template), then the solution should be moving the element into **level3**'s template.